# Crashed: NSManagedObjectContext +[ALAssetsLibrary _library]

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, nsmanagedobjectcontext, alassetslibrary

My app is crashing randomly with some users.
It looks like the crash happens when the app tries to save video and photos to gallery. It's the only point I used ALAssetsLibrary.

This is the crash report I'm receiving on Crashlytics:

```
Crashed: NSManagedObjectContext 0x106be1be0: +[ALAssetsLibrary _library]
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1860a4430 objc_msgSend + 16
1  CoreData                       0x1895e9d24 -[_PFManagedObjectReferenceQueue _processReferenceQueue:] + 1880
2  CoreData                       0x1895f043c -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processRecentChanges:] + 132
3  CoreData                       0x18968a710 -[NSManagedObjectContext _mergeChangesFromDidSaveDictionary:usingObjectIDs:] + 4944
4  PhotoLibraryServices           0x1947187bc -[PLManagedObjectContext _mergeChangesFromDidSaveDictionary:usingObjectIDs:] + 468
5  CoreData                       0x189695570 __90+[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSCoreDataSPI) _mergeChangesFromRemoteContextSave:intoContexts:]_block_invoke.1514 + 72
6  CoreData                       0x18968aea4 developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 156
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x1867c5048 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x1867cdae8 _dispatch_queue_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56
9  CoreData                       0x18968ada8 -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 304
10 CoreData                       0x189694be4 +[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSCoreDataSPI) _mergeChangesFromRemoteContextSave:intoContexts:] + 3404
11 PhotoLibraryServices           0x194715f00 __108+[PLManagedObjectContext mergeChangesFromRemoteContextSave:intoAllContextsNotIdenticalTo:completionHandler:]_block_invoke + 160
12 AssetsLibraryServices          0x194350d98 __pl_dispatch_async_block_invoke + 36
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x1867c5088 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x1867c5048 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x1867cee48 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 528
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x1867cf7d8 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 340
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x1867d0200 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh$VARIANT$mp + 400
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x1867d84a0 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread$VARIANT$mp + 644
19 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x186a6afd0 _pthread_wqthread + 932
20 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x186a6ac20 start_wqthread + 4
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Any time I see anything with the words "core data" and "crash", my first instinct is "threads". I guess you aren't using core data directly, but it could still be threads. Are you working on the main thread?

Comment: Just checked. No, it's not working on main thread. Do you think put it on main thread will solve the problem?

Comment: It's a bit of a long shot...honestly, if it isn't too painful, I'd suggest the "correct" option would be to switch to the Photos Framework since ALAssetsLibrary has been deprecated for a while now. :-/

Comment: I know it's deprecated. I will switch to Photos Frameworks next. But for now I try to put it to run on main thread and see if it stop crashing. Thanks for you help.